# Multiple DataContext

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding

When I write something like this only the first DataContext works. The classes for DataContext come from different pages and this is a summary page. ​It is far to messy to keep building a single class for binding.

```
        pages.Home.DataContext = myULSData;
        pages.Home.DataContext = myBarcode;
```

The "XAML Finding Failures" is odd.  It gives me a error for everything not found in the other file.  In other words BatchID exists in Barcode but not in ULS_Data.
[image]

Not really very useful since all the binding does not work in the second class, Barcode.  Everything works fine in the first class.

Answer (score 0):

Probably no answer because of the holidays.

I decided to build a single massive class for all data context.  However, I will use partial classes to keep it broken into separate more manageable files.